# Как показать модальное окно?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Подскажите как показать форму модально с учетом MVVM? Т.е. обычный ShowDialog не подходит явно, т.к. не вписывается в паттерн.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Например так:

1. Для диалогового окна у вас также должна быть вью-модель. В месте, где вы хотите показать диалог, создаете экземпляр этой вью-модели.
2. Дальше может быть два варианта:

   а. Используя специальный сервис. У вас есть некоторый `IDialogService`, в котором вы можете зарегистрировать соответствие "вью / вью-модель" на этапе инициализации приложения, а также вызвать показ диалога, передав нужную вью-модель. Метод `ShowDialog()` при этом возвращает значения, аналогичные методу `Window.ShowDialog()`. Конкретный экземпляр `IDialogService` передается нужным вью-моделям извне (если вы используете DI) или просто создается по месту необходимости (что хуже).

   ```
   public interface IDialogService
   {
       void RegisterDialog<TView, TViewModel>();

       bool? ShowDialog<TViewModel>(TViewModel viewModel);
   }
   ```

   Пример реализации можно посмотреть [в ответе VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/106).

   б. Используя сообщения. У вас есть некоторое сообщение 'ShowDialogMessage', которое вы передаете мессенджеру. На это сообщение подписывается либо какое-то одно окно ("главное"), либо конкретные "родительские" окна. Зависит от желаемой степени детализации. Если при этом нужно получать "возвращаемое значение", то в сообщение нужно просто добавить соответствующее поле, которое будет заполняться в том месте, где сообщение обрабатывается.

   ```
   public class ShowDialogMessage<TViewModel>: MessageBase
   {
       public TViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

       public SomeType Result { get; set; }

       public ShowDialogMessage(TViewModel viewModel)
       {
           ViewModel = viewModel;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Касаемо мест, где создаются и показываются конкретные диалоговые окна. Их реализация может отличаться в зависимости от того, что вам нужно. Если диалоговое окно (и, соответственно, его вью-модель) у вас дженериковое (например, это просто мессадж бокс, с заголовком, текстом и типом), то это может быть одно место на все приложение. Если же диалоговые окна уникальные, то мест их показа будет несколько -- по месту на "тип" окна. Иногда это можно свести к одному месту, если использовать мапу "диалог / вью-модель" (см. метод `RegisterDialog()` в первом способе).

Comment: а. Как то не очень понятно. Что за интерфейс? Где класс который его реализует? Где он должен создаваться?

б. Тут вроде выглядит как то попроще, но основной вопрос тут в том что событие оно кинется, а код пойдет дальше. Т.е. когда показываются модальные окна код в месте вызова ShowDialog останавливается и ждет закрытия окна, а в этом случае (если я правильно понял) просто кинется событие и код дальше пойдет не дожидаясь закрытия формы.

Comment: @DarkByte он написал типичные подходы. ну а классы надо реализовывать под личные нужды. в случае отправки оповещения код не пойдет дальше пока не будут оповещены и не отработают хендлеры у подписчиков, а если у подписчика есть ShowDialog, то там и остановится, пока диалог не закроется.

Comment: Ну правда вот первый пример совсем не понятен! Пожалуйста можно пример с реализацией? А по второму примеру да, действительно работает так как задумано, только как быть если в разных местах надо показывать разные диалоговые окна? Как их фильтровать? Т.е. в качестве мессенджера я взял mvvm light, там есть готовый. Но там я допустим шлю сообщение просто 0 и по типу int его ловлю в MainWindow и вывожу диалог. А как быть если много диалоговых окон? Не использовать же по типу на каждое... Как то это попахивает говнокодом.

Comment: И кстати во втором примере как быть с возвратом значений? Ну например если я показывал не просто диалоговое окно, а MessageBox с кнопками и мне надо значить какую кнопку нажали.

Comment: @andreycha И еще такой вопрос: а где вообще эти диалоговые окна должны создаваться? Я сейчас перечитал 3-ый пункт, но не понял :(. Интересует именно вариант когда окна уникальные. Причем мне надо чтобы окно создавалось только один раз! А потом просто показывалось.

Comment: Вот смотрите что я набросал: http://pastebin.ru/T7cfWg6U. Но почему то это не работает. Не создается нигде инстанс окна. Разве он из ресурсов не должен создаться?

Comment: @DarkByte обновил ответ.

Comment: @andreycha, А где должны создаваться дочерние View при использовании мессенджера? В App.xaml.cs?

Comment: @maxwell там, где вы обрабатываете сообщение. Потому что с большей долей вероятности это вью будет являться "внутренним" для места обработки сообщения. Возможно также еще гибридные варианты -- когда есть и диалог сервис, и сообщения (оба подпункта 2).