# OpenFileDialog и MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-commands

Подскажите, каким правильно пойти путем.

На форме WPF есть кнопка "Обзор", которая должна вызвать `OpenFileDialog` и после выбора файла передать его имя в `textbox`.

Используя паттерн MVVM, я должен не менять значение textbox, а изменить соответствующие значение в VM. И вот мой вопрос. Вызов `OpenFileDialog` я должен сделать в VM как `ICommand`, или из своей формы на которой кнопка?

Comment: А как хотите. Зависит от вашего восприятия относится ли это действия к вьюмоделям или исключительно альтернативный способ ввода пользователем в текстовое поле - он ведь может путь просто написать или вставить из буфера.

Comment: Посмотрите эти вопросы, возможно, будет что-то полезное: [(1)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523553/10105), [(2)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/449911/10105), [(3)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/525998/10105).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Диалоги-краеугольный камень MVVM ибо предполагается, что VM о View ничего не знает, но должен получать от неё данные. Получаем, что с одной стороны View должна вызывать команды VM с параметрами и VM ну никак не должна работать с отображением. Т.е. диалоги относятся к View. А с другой: View не должна содержать логики/кода, а вызов диалогового окна и получение результата это какая никакая а логика/код.

Самый простой вариант: в коде View повесьте обработчик события на то событие по которому у вас должен отображаться диалог выбора файла в котором создаёте и отображаете диалог пользователю, а по факту успешного закрытия события вызываете команду VM из кода (в этом случае можно обойтись и интерфейсным методом, без объявления команды).

В код на стороне VM Должна приходить строка пути к открываемому файлу(лам) и, возможно, тип доступа (чтение/чтение-запись и тп.)

PS: Если вы придерживаетесь MVVM при разработке, имхо, главное, что следует всегда помнить: вы должны сохранять тестируемость Unit-тестами вашей VM. (т.е. если вместо M подсунуть тестовые данные, а вместо View напрямую вызвать команды у вас все публичные методы и команды должны тестироваться без танцев с бубном) Создание в VM диалогов ломает эту схему.

Вариант посложнее: 
Иногда случается так, что диалог нужен кастомный. С кучей параметров которые должны задаваться на уровне VM. И вообще возможно так, что въюха должна контролировать диалог (т.е. например сначала отобразить его, а потом начать перемещать его по экрану, а потом ещё что-то эдакое) 
В этом случае возможно воспользоваться делегатами которые вы определяете на уровне VM. Входные и выходные параметры вы определяете так же в VM. Присвоение метода делегату осуществляется в коде который относится ко View. В нем реализуется отображение диалога (или чего бы то ни было ещё) и логика поведения/управления отображением. На выход вы, в принципе, можете передавать всё что угодно, начиная от результата диалога и заканчивая объектом реализующим объявленный вами интерфейс через который вы контролируете окно. Этот вариант по коду выходит чуть компактнее варианта с интерфейсами. Тестируемость не страдает.

PSS: Имхо, "правильного" варианта вне глобального контекста задачи не существует. Помните, что "Hello World" написанный по всем канонам и стандартам это овер 100 строк кода. 
Варианты с интерфейсами/делегатами и пр. танцами с бубном и десятком сопутствующих классов специфичны, сложны в понимании, сопровождении и отладке (!) и нужны только в случае если у вас этих диалогов (разных видов) больше 3 и ожидаются ещё в будущем к тому же они все нестандартные и со сложным поведением. 
В общем "Не усложняйте" (с)

Comment: Т.о. View открывает `OpenFileDialog`, а команда в VM получает имя файла/ом как параметр?

Comment: @MaximK Именно так.

Answer (score 3):

Самый правильный способ использовать интерфейс. Создаете интерфейс

```
public interface IMessageShow
{
    //Метод для показа диалога открытия файла
    string RequestFileNameForOpen();
    // Событие изменения свойства связанного с последним открытым/сохраненным файлом
    event Action<string> LastActiveFileNameChanged;
    // Путь к последнему открытому/сохраненному файлу
    string LastActiveFileName { get; set; }
    // Стартовая папка для открытия/сохранения файла
    string InitialDirectoryFileDialogue { get; set; }
    // Заголовок окна открытия файла
    string TitleOpenFileDialogue { get; set; }
    // Фильтр файлов для окна открытия файла
    string FilterOpenFileDialogue { get; set; }

}
```

Класс реализующий интерфейс привожу не полностью, только чтоб была понятна идея

```
using FileDialogue = System.Windows.Forms; //для файловых диалогов добавить в References проекта!!!
public class MessageShow : IMessageShow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Событие изменения свойства связанного с последним открытым/сохраненным файлом
    /// </summary>
    public event Action<string> LastActiveFileNameChanged = delegate { };

    //ctor
    public MessageShow()
    {
        //для диалога открытия файла
        InitialDirectoryFileDialogue = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
        TitleOpenFileDialogue = "Открыть текстовой файл";
        FilterOpenFileDialogue = "Текстовой файл (*.txt)|*.txt|Все файлы (*.*)|*.*";
        //для диалога сохранения файла
        TitleSaveFileDialogue = "Сохранить текстовой файл";
        FilterSaveFileDialogue = FilterOpenFileDialogue;
    }
     /// <summary>
    /// Диалог открытия файла
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>путь к файлу</returns>
    public string RequestFileNameForOpen()
    {
        //не использовать System.Win32, а нужно using System.Windows.Forms;
        FileDialogue.OpenFileDialog openDialog = new FileDialogue.OpenFileDialog();
        openDialog.InitialDirectory = InitialDirectoryFileDialogue;
        openDialog.Title = TitleOpenFileDialogue;
        openDialog.Filter = FilterOpenFileDialogue;
        openDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = VistaUI;
        //показываем и проверяем,что имя файла получено
        if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == FileDialogue.DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        //результат
        LastActiveFileName = openDialog.FileName;
        //событие
        LastActiveFileNameChanged(LastActiveFileName);
        return LastActiveFileName;
    }
}
```

Далее ViewModel в конструктор нужно передавать параметр типа IMessageShow

```
class SideBViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private IMessageShow message;

    //ctor
    public SideBViewModel(IMessageShow message)
    {
        this.message = message;
        message.LastActiveFileNameChanged += Message_LastActiveFileNameChanged;
    }
    //свойство куда будет сохранено имя и путь файла, кот.хочет открыть юзер
    private string _FromShowQuestion;
    public string FromShowQuestion
    {
        get { return _FromShowQuestion; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _FromShowQuestion, value); }
    }
    //обработка события
    private void Message_LastActiveFileNameChanged(string obj)
    {
        FromShowQuestion = message.LastActiveFileName;
    }

    //команда для кнопки открытия диалога
    private RelayCommand _FileOpenCommand;
    public RelayCommand FileOpenCommand
    {
        get { return _FileOpenCommand = _FileOpenCommand ?? new RelayCommand(OnFileOpen); }
    }
    //метод вызываемой командой
    private void OnFileOpen()
    {
        message.RequestFileNameForOpen();
    }
....
}
```

Как-то так.

Comment: Уточню, правильно ли я понял?  1. Создаем интерфейс. 2 В классе реализации интерфейса вызываем `OpenFileDialog` и присваиваем полученное имя файла нужному полю. 3. В VM создаем команду для открытия этого самого диалога через интерфейс. 4. Кнопку в View привязываем к команде в VM

Comment: Судя по приведённому коду вы верно поняли. Но интерфейс возможно заменить делегатом, что уменьшит объём кода (добавил описание варианта с делегатом в свой ответ). И насчёт "правильности" я бы поспорил. Ну или хотя бы ознакомился бы с авторитетным источником критериев по которым эта "правильность" определена.

Comment: @MaximK да вы поняли правильно, вы в своей программе используете реализацию интерфейса с OpenFileDialog, а в юнит-тестах можете реализовать интерфейс упрощенно, т.е. напрямую отдавая сразу имя  нужного файла например.

Comment: @Alexey делегат хорош для единичного метода. А через интерфейс я могу реализовать вызовы сразу нескольких методов: открыть файл, сохранить файл, показать сообщение и т.п. А теперь представьте сколько же вам делегатов надо будет передавать через конструктор в этом случае?

Comment: @Bulson ни в какой конструктор делегаты не передаются Кол-во делегатов будет равно кол-ву ваших методов. Но при этом объём кода будет меньше. Работа с файлом - задача VM, а не интерфейса и его реализации на стыке V и VM. Задача диалога-получить путь к файлу и ничего более ибо SOLID.

Comment: @Alexey ну вообще то, а зачем тогда я весь это код показывал, как раз чтоб работу с файлом производить на стороне VM, а диалог показывать на стороне View. А вот хваленого кода вашего я так нигде и не увидел кстати.

Comment: @Alexey вы уж не стесняйтесь покажите, как вы во VM делегат передавать будете.

Comment: @Bulson я пока ничего не хвалил. Если вы знаете C# объявить делегат в VM->инициализировать в V не составит труда. И ничего никуда не передаётся. По этой причине мне откровенно лень приводить примеры кода, ибо реализация элементарна. А вот зачем вы вы весь этот код показывали, я не знаю, это не ко мне.

Comment: @Alexey SOLID говоришь... Больше вопросов к вам не имею.

Answer (score 2):

Если значение для `TextBox` берется из `VM`, то однозначно:

> Вызов OpenFileDialog я должен сделать в VM как ICommand

так как результат `OpenFileDialog` нужно присвоить свойству, к которому привязывается `TextBox`:

> я должен не менять значение textbox, а изменить соответствующие значение в VM