# Обновить ListBox после вызова диалога выбора каталога

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Имеем C# WPF MVVM, ниже описание,  при открытии приложения ListBox заполняется именами папок, которые находятся в выбранном каталоге, а в TextBlock отображается полный путь к каталогу в котором лежат эти папки, первоначально каталог выбирается текущий каталог приложения (в конструкторе MainViewModel), потом хочу сменить каталог, нажимаю кнопку "Кнопка 'Диалог выбора каталога'" , выбираю каталог и .....

в ListBox строки добавляются при каждом выборе нового каталога строки прибавляются, а в TextBlock всегда висит один и тот же путь .

Подскажите пожалуйста:
как куда и что надо написать вставить чтобы при выборе каталога ListBox показывал  список папок , а TextBlock полный путь к выбранному каталогу.

[image: скрин приложения]

Кратко описание проекта основных моментов

[image: проект]

**Модель**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace mvvmProj003.Model
{

    public class Catalog
    {
        public string CatalogName { get; set; }  // имя каталога
        public string CatalogPath { get; set; }  // полный путь к каталогу
        public string DirName{ get; set; }       // имя папки (вложенные в каталог,1вложеность) 
        public string DirPath { get; set; }      // полный путь к этой папке


        public Catalog[] GetSpisokDir(string path) // функция делаем массив классов
        {
            List<Catalog> list = new List<Catalog>(); // список классов 

            string nameCat = Path.GetFileName(path); // имя каталога получаем из полного пути

            foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) // перебираем папки в нашем каталоге 
            {
                 string nameDir = Path.GetFileName(dir); // имя папки из полного пути

                // заполняем очередной элемент нашего списка    
                list.Add(new Catalog {      
                     CatalogName = nameCat,
                     CatalogPath = path,
                     DirName     = nameDir,
                     DirPath     = dir
                });
            }
             
            return list.ToArray(); // возвращаем список преобразованный в массив классов
        }
    }

}
```

**ViewModel**

BaseVM.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace mvvmProj003.ViewModel
{
    public class BaseVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
                return false;

            field = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

CatalogVM.cs

```
using mvvmProj003.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace mvvmProj003.ViewModel
{
    public class CatalogVM : BaseVM
    {
        public CatalogVM(string first, string second, string third, string fourth )
        {
            this.firstVM  = first;
            this.secondVM = second;
            this.thirdVM  = third;
            this.fourthVM = fourth;
        }                       

        private string firstVM;
        public string FirstVM
        {
            get => firstVM;
            set => Set(ref firstVM, value);
        }

        private string secondVM;
        public string SecondVM
        {
            get => secondVM;
            set => Set(ref secondVM, value);
        }

        private string thirdVM;
        public string ThirdVM
        {
            get => thirdVM;
            set => Set(ref thirdVM, value);
        }

        private string fourthVM;
        public string FourthVM
        {
            get => fourthVM;
            set => Set(ref fourthVM, value);
        }

    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using mvvmProj003.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace mvvmProj003.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<CatalogVM> SpisokDir { get; set; }
        public Catalog CatDir { get; set; }
        
        // команда открываем диалог выбора каталога
        private RelayCommand openDialog;
        public RelayCommand OpenDialog
        {
            get
            {
                return openDialog ??
                  (openDialog = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                  {
                      FolderBrowserDialog fBD = new FolderBrowserDialog(); // диалоговое окно
                      DialogResult        result = fBD.ShowDialog();       // показываем диалоговое окно

                      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fBD.SelectedPath)) // если выбрали каталог
                      {
                          //SpisokDir = new ObservableCollection<CatalogVM>();
                          //CatDir    = new Catalog();
                          LoadModel(fBD.SelectedPath); // 
                      }
                  }));
            }
        }


        public MainViewModel() // конструктор  
        {
            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // определяем текущий каталог

            SpisokDir = new ObservableCollection<CatalogVM>();
            CatDir    = new Catalog();
            LoadModel(path);
        }

        private void LoadModel(string path)
        {
            // в модель передаем путь к каталогу и перебираем массив классов
            foreach (var cat in CatDir.GetSpisokDir(path))
            {
                SpisokDir.Add(new CatalogVM(
                    cat.CatalogName,
                    cat.CatalogPath,
                    cat.DirName,
                    cat.DirPath
                    ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RelayCommand.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace mvvmProj003.ViewModel
{
         
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SpisokDir}" Margin="45,42,43,0" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FFD0EEB8">
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding SecondVM}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center"><Run/></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
<Button   Command="{Binding OpenDialog}" ToolTip="Кнопка 'Диалог выбора каталога'" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,42,8,0" Background="#FFFDFBED" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="30">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/открыть каталог.png" Width="22" Height="22"/>
            </StackPanel>


        </Button>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SpisokDir}" Margin="10,108,8,29">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/db.png" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ThirdVM}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: На SO принято задавать **один** вопрос, а не кучу вопросов в одном. По поводу ваших вопросов, то: 1. Я бы сказал и нет и да, ибо вы скопировали из интернета куски кода, собрали некого франкенштейна (причем очень грязного) и я уверен, что вы не сможете объяснить, что делает каждая строчка кода (из-за чего у вас много лишнего). Ну то есть у вас есть серьезная проблема с именованием (`GetSpisokDir`), у вас есть смесь WPF + WinForms, у вас в XAML `Margin="10,108,8,29"` и ряд других проблем, INPC используете всегда, ну и так далее...

Comment: 2. Зависит от того, что именно и как вы хотите, можете привязать нужный VM к нужному View, можете вовсе обойтись [XAML](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553), решений много. 3. Вынесите логику загрузки в отдельную команду и вызывайте ее, либо следите за изменениями в директории и обновляйте в реальном времени, опять же, вариантов уйма.

Comment: спасибо за ответ,  как обойтись одним XAML

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста что лишнее ? я уберу и перезадам вопрос

Comment: Если говорить именно про MVVM, то вы его нарушаете, ибо диалоги, это в какой-то мере View часть, которую по правилам MVVM отделяют от общей логики, оборачивают интерфейсами и так далее. Можете глянуть допустим [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576471/220553). А по поводу "а в TextBlock всегда висит один и тот же путь" - а где вы это делаете? Допустим `<TextBlock  Text="{Binding SecondVM}"` это нужный текстбокс, ок, привязан, а где этому значению задается что либо? Вот я вижу у вас метод `private void LoadModel(string path)`, он заполняет коллекцию, ок, а менять свойство текстбокса?

Comment: `подскажите пожалуйста что лишнее ?` - вы про код или вопрос? Если про вопрос, то он содержит 3 вопроса в одном: 1. Почему не обновляет текстбокс. 2. Правильно-ли реализовал? 3. Как обновить интерфейс. Сейчас вот допустим мне с чем вам помогать? Ибо как видите, мне пришлось затронуть все и написать 3 коммента (либо здоровый пост с разбором), когда я мог сделать акцент на одном.

Comment: свойство текстбокса  привязано к колекции

Comment: ОК сейчас уберу лишнии вопросы

Comment: ОК  поправил ,  оставил только вопрос "чтобы при выборе каталога ListBox показывал список папок , а TextBlock полный путь к выбранному каталогу."

Comment: "свойство текстбокса привязано к колекции" - а как вы себе это представляете? Вот вы написали `<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SpisokDir}" ... ><TextBlock  Text="{Binding SecondVM}" ... /></StackPanel>`, где `SpisokDir` - это `ObservableCollection<CatalogVM>` и допустим у вас в ней 100 элементов, из какого именно свойств из 100, должно взяться значение и занестить в `TextBox`?

Comment: из любого , потому что будет одно и тоже значение

Comment: Ну это так не работает, как по логическим соображениям, так и по техническим. Попробуйте, например в коде напишите `SpisokDir.SecondVM`, что получите? Наверно ошибку, ибо `ObservableCollection` не содержит в себе такого свойства. Вообще, разбейте свое приложение на небольшие кусочки, которые будут отвечать за что-то одно и потом подумайте, правильно-ли хранить путь внутри объекта, который находится в коллекции, или это все же нечто общее и можно положить рядом с коллекцией?

Comment: <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=SpisokDir[0].SecondVM}" >   вот так работает ,   я  заполняю SpisokDir    это массив классов, в классе поле FirstVM и SecondVM у всех одно и тоже значение можно брать любое , потому что это ИМЯ и ПУТЬ к корневому каталогу а третье и четвертое поле класса заполняется именем и путем конкретно к каждой папке в этом каталоге

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто очищайте отображаемую коллекцию перед загрузкой

```cs
private void LoadModel(string path)
{
    SpisokDir.Clear();
    // ваш код
}
```

Comment: ОК в ListBox теперь происходит смена списка, т.е в зависимости какой выбрал каталог показывает список папок в этом каталоге ,   вот только теперь TextBlock не показывает выбранный путь , ни чего не показывает и первая запись исчезает, отладчиком прошел  колекция заполняеться все есть , у меня наверно как то Binding не правильно

Comment: ОК все ОК, это у меня  TextBlock глюкнул